# Issue with twitter login.(Twitter return empty Access Token)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter login for my website. It was working fine til past month or so. Now i  got a issue with that.

Issue Scenario: 
If login with twitter - it redirects to the twitter login page - user login with twitter their twitter account - but twitter returns a empty access token.

Another positive scenario: 
User already logging in their twitter account - come to my site and try to login with twitter - Now twitter login process works fine in my site.

I checked in all sites. All of them having the same problem. Specially very popular PHP tutorial blogs too. Does twitter change anything in Oauth login process or we have to use ssl for our site to avoid this issue.

Answers welcome :-)

Comment: Are you using `twitteroauth.php` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oauth for twitter login

Comment: What is the api link you are using ?

Comment: My site is in cake php. I am using oauthconsumer component.

Comment: Change your twitter api to`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/;`

Comment: I tried with that too still i face a same problem. Do you have twiiter Oauth login in your site? Does it work fine now?